# Azure CDN Multi-Origin endpoint with terraform azapi provider

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cdn, azapi

I'm trying to create an Azure CDN endpoint with one (or more) origin group(s) where each origin group has one or more origins.

I have the following code which - indeed - does not work because I'm referencing the endpoint from the origin group through the `parent_id` but I also must reference the origin group from the endpoint when I want to set the `defaultOriginGroup.id` which - of course leads to a cycle.

How can I set the `defaultOriginGroup` in a scenario like this?

If it is possible to solve this with the azurerm provider that's also fine.

```
resource "azapi_resource" "profile" {
    type = "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2022-11-01-preview"
    name = "MyPforile2"
    location =  azurerm_resource_group.main.location
    parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.main.id
    body = jsonencode({
        sku = {
            name = "Standard_Microsoft"
        }
    })
}

resource "azapi_resource" "endpoint" { 
    type = "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints@2022-11-01-preview"
    name = "MyEndpoint2"
    location = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
    parent_id = azapi_resource.profile.id
    body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
            defaultOriginGroup = {
                id = azapi_resource.originGroup.id
            },
            origins = [{
                name = "DefaultOrigin",
                properties = {
                    enabled = true,
                    hostName = "contoso.com",
                    httpPort = 80,
                    httpsPort = 443
                }
            }]
        }
    })
}

resource "azapi_resource" "originGroup" { 
    type = "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints/originGroups@2022-11-01-preview"
    name = "MyOriginGroup2"
    parent_id = azapi_resource.endpoint.id
    body = jsonencode({
        origins = [{
            id = azapi_resource.origin.id
        }]
    })
}

resource "azapi_resource" "origin" {
  type = "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints/origins@2022-11-01-preview"
  name = "MyOrigin2"
  parent_id = azapi_resource.endpoint.id
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      enabled = true
      hostName = "contoso.com"
      httpPort = 80
      httpsPort = 443
      originHostHeader = "www.contoso.com"
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found your question while I was searching for official support for multi-origin CDN using AzureRM. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/10771) about that and the short answer is that they are yet to support it.

So I tried your solution and came out with the following code to address my needs and I think I solved the issue you had to set the defaultOriginGroup.  I just provision everything together using the Endpoint API and reference the IDs as you would do when using ARM Templates.  I also use variables to name everything so building the resource IDs is less of a pain.

Its not as elegant a solution as I would like, but since I could not find a better way to handle the resource IDs, and using separate resources would cause cross-reference issues, I had no other option.

```
resource "azapi_resource" "endpoint" { 
  type = "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints@2022-11-01-preview"
  name = "EDP-${local.cdnprofile_name}"
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  parent_id = azurerm_cdn_profile.cdn.id
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      isCompressionEnabled = true,
      contentTypesToCompress = var.cdn_content_compress,
      optimizationType = "GeneralWebDelivery",
      isHttpAllowed = true,
      isHttpsAllowed = true,
      defaultOriginGroup = {
        id = "/subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}/resourcegroups/${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/${azurerm_cdn_profile.cdn.name}/endpoints/EDP-${local.cdnprofile_name}/origingroups/${var.cdn_stg_org_group_name}"
      },
      origins = [{
        name = var.cdn_stg_org_name,
        properties = {
          enabled = true,
          hostName = "contoso.com",
          httpPort = 80,
          httpsPort = 443
        }
      },
      {
        name = var.cdn_app_org_name,
        properties = {
          enabled = true,
          hostName = "contoso.com",
          httpPort = 80,
          httpsPort = 443
        }
      }],
      originGroups = [{
        name = var.cdn_stg_org_group_name,
        properties = {
          origins = [{
            id = "/subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}/resourcegroups/${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/${azurerm_cdn_profile.cdn.name}/endpoints/EDP-${local.cdnprofile_name}/origins/${var.cdn_stg_org_name}"
          }] 
        }
      },
      {
        name = var.cdn_app_org_group_name,
        properties = {
          origins = [{
            id = "/subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}/resourcegroups/${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/${azurerm_cdn_profile.cdn.name}/endpoints/EDP-${local.cdnprofile_name}/origins/${var.cdn_app_org_name}"
          }] 
        }
      }]
    }
  })
}
```